# How can I find out why ISAPI is returning a 302 status for a specific file?

Tags: redirect, asp-classic, iis-10, http-status-code-302

I have a website hosted served by IIS 10 on a Windows Server (2019) running Plesk. The site is mainly Classic ASP. I have a staging subdomain at `staging.example.com`, with the production site at `www.example.com`.

The two are fairly strictly separated, except that I don’t store image files, PDFs and such things on the staging server; I have a URL rewrite directive that redirects to the production site with a 302 status based on the URL *not* matching the following regex:

```
\.(php|asp|js|css|csv|json|htm|html|svg|svgz)(\?.+)?$
```

This generally works well: ASP pages are served from the staging site when the staging URL is called, but images on the page are pulled from the production site.

Except that there’s one ASP file which – for some reason – gives a 302 and redirects to the production site no matter what I do. The file exists in both locations. I’ve tested the URL in the pattern tester provided in the IIS URL-rewrite section, and it matches the pattern (meaning it *shouldn’t* redirect).

When I trace the request (that is, the initial request to the staging URL) in Firefox’s browser console, I get the following response headers (redacted):

```
HTTP/2 302 Found
cache-control: no-cache
content-type: text/html
location: https://www.example.com/path/to/file.asp
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
set-cookie: ASPSESSION****=********; secure; path=/
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
x-powered-by-plesk: PleskWin
date: Sun, 19 Dec 2021 18:52:05 GMT
content-length: 201
    
Accept
    text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding
    gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language
    en-US,en;q=0.5
Authorization
    Basic *************
Connection
    keep-alive
Cookie
    [cookies]
Host
    staging.example.com
Referer
    https://staging.example.com/path/to/file.asp
Sec-Fetch-Dest
    document
Sec-Fetch-Mode
    navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site
    same-origin
Sec-Fetch-User
    ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests
    1
User-Agent
    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:96.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/96.0
```

I’ve painstakingly gone through the entire file and all the file includes within it, and I can’t find any kind of `Response.Redirect` in any of them that might be responsible.

So it seems it’s IIS that’s redirecting with a 302… despite the fact that there doesn’t seem to be a directive that tells it to do this.

Is there a way to trace exactly *what* on the server is causing this 302 for one specific file? Some sort of tracing mechanism that tells me where the request gets passed on to before the 302 response is returned?

---

#### Update 26 Dec

Based on samwu’s comment, I’ve enabled [Failed Request Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) for the page, and looking through the resulting .frb file, it’s clear that none of the rewrite conditions are met – they all have `succeed: false`. It seems the redirect is not happening in the WWW Server at all, in fact, but in the ISAPI extension. This is the only place that the production site URL is mentioned at all in the request trace (except of course in the `GENERAL_RESPONSE_HEADER` section at the very end):

```
ISAPI_START 
    MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_SUCCESS_STATUS  ModuleName="IsapiModule", Notification="EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER", HttpStatus="302", HttpReason="Object moved"
    GENERAL_SET_RESPONSE_HEADER HeaderName="Location", HeaderValue="https://www.example.com/path/to/file.asp", Replace="false"
    GENERAL_SET_RESPONSE_HEADER HeaderName="Content-Length", HeaderValue="201", Replace="false"
    GENERAL_SET_RESPONSE_HEADER HeaderName="Content-Type", HeaderValue="text/html", Replace="false"
    GENERAL_SET_RESPONSE_HEADER HeaderName="Cache-control", HeaderValue="no-cache", Replace="false"
    NOTIFY_MODULE_COMPLETION    ModuleName="IsapiModule", Notification="EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER", fIsPostNotificationEvent="false", CompletionBytes="0", ErrorCode="The operation completed successfully. (0x0)"
ISAPI_END
```

In the ISAPI Filters section in IIS Manager, there are four filters: a 32-bit and a 64-bit version for ASP.Net 2.0 and the same for ASP.Net 4.0, all called `aspnet_filter.dll`. I’m guessing these are standard filters – I know for certain, at least, that we haven’t mucked about with any ISAPI filters at all.

As should be obvious by now, I’m not really a server admin, and ISAPI filters are *definitely* above my level of knowledge.

So how do I proceed from here? How do I figure out why ISAPI is redirecting?

Comment: You can try to use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) or fiddler.

Comment: @samwu Thanks for the pointer – I hadn’t realised I could use FRT for this, but it more or less worked. At least it showed me that the redirect is being applied by an ISAPI filter (see update), though that unfortunately doesn’t get me much further…

Comment: You can also check HTTP.sys Logging, the path is `%SystemRoot%\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR`, this log records responses to clients, connection time-outs, and orphaned requests. This additional information can help you troubleshoot HTTP-based issues, which are logged before the request reaches IIS.

Comment: @samwu As far as I can tell, that log file (which goes back about eight days) doesn’t contain any references to the page in question at all. There are a number of other files on the server that show up in there, but not this one. Most of it is just a bunch of `TimerConnection_Idle` statuses. But if this is logged before reaching IIS, and the request reaches IIS with the correct staging URL (which gets correctly evaluated by URL rewrite directives), would this be expected to show anything relevant?

Comment: You need to check the content of this file, and how do you use failed request tracking, usually there will be a detailed request process.

Comment: @samwu Which file do you mean? There is quite a detailed request process in the FRT file, but the only thing I can find that relates to the redirect is the part quoted in the update to the question. When I go through the HTTPERR log, I don’t see anything that looks at all relevant. Here’s a [ZIP file containing the full FRT and excerpts from the HTTPERR log](https://easyupload.io/87rsnl) (server details redacted from FRT and only entries from the relevant time period from the HTTPERR log included).

Comment: Sorry, I can’t download the file for some reason, I suggest you open a [support ticket](https://support.microsoft.com) for this.